# First layer lines don't stick at all

Tags: print-quality, ultimaker-original

My Ultimaker 1 with a heated bed doesn't print good first layer lines at all. The single lines keep detaching from the printbed, no matter what nozzle or bed temperature or the height of printhead from printbed. I cleaned the printbed thouroughly, too. It worked a while ago, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Data:

Ultimaker 1 with Heated Printbed (Glass)
PLA @ 200°/60°

This is how it looks like after removing a print (one and a half layers) from the printbed.
It is quite thick though.
[image]

Comment: Besides this question possibly being a duplicate (there have been quite a few questions on adhesion already) there isn't really enough detail in your question either. What material are you printing with, what temperatures are you printing at, what material do you have on the bed to promote adhesion, what does your first layer look like (picture)?

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: recommend closing as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This looks a bit like your build plate isn't level. I'd suggest re-leveling using feeler gauges.

Comment: Problem is, the print bed can be really tight or loose and everything inbetween. It does not matter at all.